# apache error - Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I've tried all the answers to this question I can find, but none resolve this error. I'm trying to simply server a list of files with apache. My /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf has

```
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so

DocumentRoot "/home/<user>/public_html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
</IfModule>
```

/home/[user]/public_html is a symlink to /home/[user]/[folder of files to server]

When I go to "http://[my ip address] I get the forbidden error. If I go to 127.0.0.1 I get a failed to connect error.

Comment: probably a folder permission issue. what account is apache running on?  (it's probably called something like `www` or `www-data` or `nobody` or `apache` or `httpd` )

Comment: The User and Group were set to apache. I changed them to both be the owner of the folder I'm trying to serve, now when I try to connect it's just stuck eternally loading.

Comment: un-do that, set them back to apache/apache, and run `sudo su apache -s /bin/bash -c 'namei -l /home/<user>/public_html'`, what do you get?

Comment: I got it working by chowning /etc/httpd to the user I set in the httpd.conf file. Running your command, -l wasn't a valid option, but no options gave permission denied on the user directories.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about Linux usage. I suggest to re-ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com .